# how do I add a udev property for my Android phone?

Tags: ubuntu, udev, android

I'm trying to get my Android phone recognised by rhythmbox.

Talking to upstream, rhythmbox [gets the value](https://git.gnome.org/browse/rhythmbox/tree/shell/rb-removable-media-manager.c#n892) of "id_model" for the udev device - if it is "Android" then it should work.

How do I use a udev rule to assign the "id_model" property to be "Android"?

---

Currently my /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules contains

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1ebf", ATTR{idProduct}=="7f29", SYMLINK+="Android%n",  MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

This appears to be working because I can see my device with `ls -l /dev/Android4`

My `lsusb` doesn't appear to have a description associated with this phone

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 1ebf:7f29
```

Running `udevadm info -q all -a /dev/Android4` gives me [this list of info](http://pastebin.com/P30PV1iZ) - I don't see id_model in this list.